# Dragging out of NSTableView to Remove

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` that contains a number of items. I'd like to implement dragging from *inside* and dropping *outside* of the NSTableView to delete the dragged item. (Kind of like how Safari 'poofs' bookmarks away.)

The `NSTableView` is already configured to support drag n' drop reordering, and accepts drops from another `NSTableView` in the application, so while most of it is wired up, I'm just missing a small piece of functionality.

**Update:**

Thanks to **Sean** for his help so far. While I can receive notification that an item has been dragged out after it has floated its way back to its original position (see comment to his answer), I'd like to receive notification immediately once the mouse button is released.

The current behavior is for the user to drag-drop an item out, the drag to be treated as "not valid," and for the item to animate back to its original position. *Then* the notification is received, and I'm able to remove the item, but it's a little confusing (for users) from a UI standpoint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like your table view is already implementing the `NSDraggingSource` protocol. In this case you can add the method `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:` (pre OS 10.7) or `draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` (OS 10.7) which will supply the operation `NSDragOperationNone` in the `operation` argument if the drag failed. Thus, you can check if this operation was passed, then delete the object and remove it from the view if so.

In other words, it would look something like this (in 10.7) :

```
-(void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session endedAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation {
    if (operation == NSDragOperationNone) {
        //delete object, remove from view, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do these methods need to be defined in the NSTableView, or in the object that is acting as the delegate/datasource? I didn't need to subclass the NSTableView to provide the current level of dragging functionality, just implemented a few delegate methods and called registerForDraggedTypes:. Implementing the dragging methods you recommended in the datasource/delegate didn't seem to work, but I'll try them in subclassed versions of the NSTableViews.

Comment: It worked by adding them to the subclassed NSTableView, but the problem is that the application treats the drag as "bad", and the image floats back to its original location, *then* the above methods are called. Any way to receive a notification immediately when the mouse button is released?

Comment: I was able to figure that last part out. In my subclassed NSTableView, I simply overrode: **dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:** and then passed that method to [super ...], while changing the slideBack: parameter to NO.

Comment: You should combine `operation == NSDragOperationNone` with `!NSPointInRect(screenPoint, self.view.window.frame)` to avoid the object being deleted if dragged back to its original place before dragging started.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the drag image floating back to its original location before the deletion, you can set the dragging session property "animatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail" in the tableView:draggingSession:willBeginAtPoint:forRowIndexes: method:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes {
   [session setAnimatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail:NO];
}
```

However I am still searching for  method to create the "poof" when deleting a dragged row.

Comment: It's not a method, but a function: [`NSShowAnimationEffect`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSShowAnimationEffect)

Comment: Thanks for that Peter. I am now using this:

NSShowAnimationEffect(NSAnimationEffectPoof, [NSEvent mouseLocation], NSZeroSize, nil, nil, nil);

Comment: how i can find out in this method what the draggingoperation is? when you do this [session setAnimatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail:NO]; it always don't go back... but i just want this when i delete a row... The second question is, i want just delete the row when my dragged item is out of my application window... it should be possible with endedAtPoint but i have no idea how? hope you can help :)