# How to NSAnimationEffect in swift

Tags: swift, nstableview, nsanimation

I'm trying to play an animation when I remove an item from a `NSTableView` by dragging the item out of the window.

According to the documentation, its usually done using. `NSAnimationEffect`.

> These effects are used to indicate that an item was removed from a
> collection, such as a toolbar, without deleting the underlying data.
> See NSShowAnimationEffect(*:*:*:*:*:*:).

But I'm not sure how to use this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dragging out of NSTableView to Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707034/dragging-out-of-nstableview-to-remove)

Comment: I have already implemented the item removal from the tableview. Now I'm trying to add an animation like the "puff of smoke" animation that played when a dock item is removed in previous builds of macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't notice that `NSAnimationEffect` had a `show()` method. That seems to do the trick.

```
let loc = NSEvent.mouseLocation
NSAnimationEffect.poof.show(centeredAt: NSPoint(x: loc.x, y: loc.y), size: NSSize(width: 40, height: 40))
}
```